# How to solve the error: Not allowed to start service Intent : app is in background uid?

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I have a service which started by on booted completed event it, but the app crashes with the error message as in above. Please help on how can I start my Service on BroadCast receiver event of Boot_Completed.

**MyService.kt**

```
class MyService : Service() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate")
    }
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "DO SOME STAFF")
    }
}
```

**MyBroadCaster.kt**

```
class StartRelayServiceAtBootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
     override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED == intent.action) {
            val serviceIntent = Intent(context, MyService::class.java)
            context.startService(serviceIntent)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upon some searching I got the answer that I had to check the SDK version that I can then start it as foreground service or just with starteService;

```
class StartRelayServiceAtBootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED == intent.action) {
            val intent = Intent(context, MyService::class.java)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                context.startForegroundService(intent)
            } else {
                context.startService(intent)
            }
            Log.i("Autostart", "started")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are limitations on apps in the background. Obviously, if the device just booted, all apps are "in the background". You cannot start a `Service` from a background app. You probably need to use `JobScheduler` to to what you want.

See this document for a discussion about the limitations on background apps and how to migrate to other solutions that are allowed:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Comment: Great thank you. I looked to it and it helped me to understand the limitation on background service which helped me to further searching and got the answer as I posted. Thank you

Comment: If the answer was helpful you should accept it by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer. This will remove the question from the list of unanswered questions and improve your accept rate, as well as giving me some reputation points. Or you can accept your own answer.